# about jquery image zoom effect

Tags: jquery, zooming, thumbnails

I have the following code with some thumbnails:

```
<img onclick="if($(this).hasClass('zoom'{
      this.src='http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2uql6rJsI1r9fv99o1_100.gif'; 
      $(this).animate({'width':'100','height':'50'}).removeClass('zoom')
   }else{
      this.src='http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2uql6rJsI1r9fv99o1_500.gif';
      $(this).animate({'width':'500','height':'268'}).addClass('zoom')
   }"
   style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"
   src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2uql6rJsI1r9fv99o1_100.gif" >
```

It works, but I don't want this style for my website, I want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">#$^%@^&*$#$^#@%</script>
```

But too complicated, I can not write...so who can help me?

SOURCE IT HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/My39T/

Another problem is, I need to animate, so these images need width/height. I can do this, but I don't have the images width/height, so maybe need this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
$(this).attr('height',$(this).height());
$(this).attr('width',$(this).width());
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear,what this means #$^%@^&*$#$^#@%?which style you want?

Comment: @Peeyush: I think the string of indecipherable characters is his way of communicating that he doesn't understand JavaScript.

Comment: #$^%@^&*$#$^#@%   =====  <script type="text/javascript">js.js</script>
 some like this

Comment: Please ask one question at a time clearly. What do you mean by `<script type="text/javascript">#$^%@^&*$#$^#@%</script>` ? What do you want to accomplish? I've edited your code for formatting and cleaned up language / grammar / capitalization. It's up to you, however to make your question coherent. If you can do that, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want, but because you didn't clearly state exactly what you wanted to happen, this is a best-guess based on reading the in-line `onclick` handler.

```
$(function() {
    $(".thumb > li > a").click(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            img = that.find('img'),
            src = that.href,
            h = img.height(),
            w = img.width();

        img.attr({
            'height' : h,
            'width' : w,
            'src' : src
        });
        if (that.hasClass('zoom')){
            img.animate(
                {
                    'height' : 67,
                    'width' : 100
                },1000);
        }
        else {
            img.animate(
                {
                    'height' : 268,
                    'width' : 500
                },1000);
        }
        that.toggleClass('zoom');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/My39T/2/).

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: yea, thanks man, but you source just zoom this thumb pic, not zoomout to this big pic....

Comment: Which is remarkably odd, since right-clicking (in Chrome/Firebug) and 'inspect element' shows that the `src` has updated to the new value. =/

Comment: Okay, this seems odd. If you set the new `src` to a string for another image, elsewhere, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/My39T/3/). If you change the `href` of the `a` to point to the same image (as in the previous example) [it fails](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/My39T/4/). I have *no* idea why.

Comment: yap, and i use php getimagesize get this height/width but too slow, so i want jquery do this, because .animate need this.

Comment: i got it, "src = that.attr('href')," be good.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/My39T/8/   I did my best!but.......Imperfect